# Intrinsic semiconductor having less conductivity than extrinsic conductor

Tags: electrons, electrical-resistance, semiconductor-physics, conductors, electronic-band-theory

The question is quite simple.Why intrinsic semiconductor has less conductivity than extrinsic semiconductor? I want to know the exact doping concentration per atoms in extrinsic semiconductor relative to room temperature excited intrinsic ions.

Comment: I don't have actual data, but it is only obvious why extrinsic semiconductor has greater conductivity: they have charge carriers **in addition** to intrinsically generated charge carriers (holes and electrons).

Comment: @samjoe Thanks for your reply.I know about the number of charge carriers being more in extrinsic than in intrinsic.Its just that i want to know how many dopant atoms are injected per Si or Ge atoms.And how that differentiates from the number of electrons being free in intrinsic semiconductor,both at room temperature

Comment: Intrinsic Si populations are order 10$^{12}$ per cc. Doping levels are 10$^{15}$ to 10$^{20}$ per cc. See the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intrinsic semiconductors have a dissociated population (a bunch of
holes and electrons that separate due to temperature, and can
contribute to conduction until they recombine).   Because a high
population of holes and electrons would cause a very FAST
rate of recombination (faster than thermal generation occurs) , and a very low population of holes or
electrons would cause very SLOW recombination (slower than thermal
generation of pairs), it should be no surprise that
at equilibrium, the fractional population of holes $ n_p$ and electrons $n_e$,
is related by an equation
$$constant = n_p \times n_e = n_i^2$$
where the $n_i^2$ symbolizes the at-thermal-equilibrium
numbers of holes and also of electrons.

For intrinsic silicon, $$n_p = n_e = n_i$$

Doping generates a large number of (for instance) electrons, pushing $n_e$ up,
and by the equilibrium equation, forces $n_p$ down.   But, conduction
of electricity depends on the SUM of the holes and electrons.   If one
has  undoped material conduction is 
$$K  \times (n_e + n_p)  = K \times 2 n_i$$
but for  $n_e = 100 \times n_i$ doped material, that conduction goes
up to $$ K \times (n_e + n_p) = K \times 100.01 \times n_i$$

That's the basics (but holes are less mobile than electrons and
the real conductivity is a messier formula).

All doped silicon has more charge carriers than if it were intrinsic (undoped).
The doping level is controllable over many orders of magnitude, 
which allows a wide range of properties of near pure material.